# Path to .css file uploaded to Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Created a simple Azure function that serves up a single web page.  Uploaded 2 css files that I would like the web page to use.

[image: Print Screen of Azure Function files]

Not sure what path to use with the .css files so the browser finds it:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** `<link rel="stylesheet" href="D:\home\site\wwwroot\HomeWebApp\main.css">`

**Detailed answer:**
You can discover this by launching the Kudu console.  Here are the steps:

1. Visit the Azure Portal for your Function App.
2. Select **Platform features->Advanced tools (Kudu)**
3. Select **Debug console->CMD**
4. On the command prompt, type `cd site\wwwroot\HomeWebApp` The path you see in the prompt is the path to the directory containing your main.css file.